# XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "Popup" in my xct:popup xaml file

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

How to solve the below error that appears in output window:

> XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "Popup".

My code:

```
 <xct:Popup  xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit" 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="SWD_Trening.NewEvent"
    IsLightDismissEnabled="False"
    Size="1000,600"/>

   <StackLayout>


   </StackLayout>
 </xct:Popup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to include the namespace where the popup is defined:

#### Xamarin Forms

```
xmlns:xct="clr-namespace:Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;assembly=Xamarin.CommunityToolkit"
```

Please take a look at the official documentation: [Xamarin Forms communitytoolkit popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/popup)

#### MAUI

```
xmlns:xct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
```

Please take a look at the official documentation: [MAUI communitytoolkit popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup#including-the-xaml-namespace)

Comment: Cannot find   version 2022

Comment: sorry my bad it was for MAUI, check my edit for Xamarin forms

Comment: Great it worked as a wish